# How did my Windows 7 just manage to download and install a bunch of updates if "auto updates" is turned off?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I know for sure that "auto updates" was disabled before the restart, and they are still disabled now. Yet, when I did the restart Windows showed me the percent ticker during shutdown, during restart, and I can actually see names of newly installed updates with today's date in Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Updates.

Is this a known issue? Does Windows just brazenly ignore the prohibition of updates when it feels like it?

Can anybody suggest firewall level solutions to this, like prohibiting Windows or some parts of Windows from communicating with the Internet?

ETA: OK, some Internet research turns up similar claims, e.g. [see here](http://www.microsoft-watch.com/content/operating_systems/windows_updates_sneaky_updates.html)

Comment: How long ago was your last restart?

Comment: about 2 minutes. Enough to run through the percent ticker, like I said. I am not sure if it did downloading during restart; maybe it downloaded previously and proceeded to do installation now.

Comment: Some "important" updates will install automatically.

Comment: Other than an IT setting where updates need compatibility testing, usually the only people that turn off automatic updates are the ones that are afraid of a Windows Genuine Advantage update.

Comment: @EndangeringSpecies Disable the Windows Update service if you totally do not wan those updates

Comment: @DustinG. I turn it off so it can't automatically restart my computer... closing every program I have open... have you ever tried to recover 10 open programs, at least 4 of which don't auto-save (notepad, cmd, etc)? It's not nice.

Comment: I don't have that problem because I usually install updates before Windows resorts to installing them and rebooting my system for me. I also regularly save the things I am working on.

Comment: Rather than stopping Windows Update - you can [stop it from automatically rebooting your system using Group Policy](http://www.techspot.com/guides/230-prevent-automatic-windows-update-restarts/). This will work if you have Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate.

Comment: @EndangeringSpecies, soandos was asking how long it had been since the *previous* reboot. That is, maybe you had a **pending** update that did not finish installing until the subsequent reboot.

Comment: @Dustin: If you're manually updating before auto-update kicks in, then you're not really using auto-update. And how do you suggest one "saves their work" in the middle of a 12-hour render job or save unsaveable program states or workspace configurations?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté What I am saying is that it's important to find time to maintain your machine and you won't run into the issue. Are you saying that you can NEVER close your applications or reboot your machine? It is extremely important when you are doing such work to be proactive with such maintenance on your system. Also, I never claimed that I was using auto-update, what I was saying is I take the time to save and close my work and perform the updates myself on a regular basis.

Answer (score 3):

Dustin G mentioned this in a comment but I thought it merited a proper answer.

As has been said in comments, there are some updates the MS determine to be so important that they will be installed regardless, giving you no option to preview them.

What makes this irksome is that it will accompany the install with an auto reboot, which may may interfere with long-running e.g. overnight tasks.

if the windows version is suitable (eg Pro, Enterprise etc...) then you can prevent the auto reboot through Group Policy. (**this won't stop the install, just present you with the standard reboot reminder dialog that you get when you manually run updates, rather than one that has a countdown timer to do it anyway**)

open the local group policy editor:

```
Win 7: type gpedit.msc into the search box on the start menu
Vista: start->run-> type gpedit.msc
```

navigate to the following setting:

```
Local Computer Policy->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Update->No Auto-Restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations
```

double click it to open it up and select "Enable" to prevent the timeout of the restart dialog.

If you don't have access to gpedit.msc due to your Windows SKU, then create the registry entry directly: (create any keys that don't already exist)

32bit:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

create a DWORD value called **NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers** and set the value to 1

64bit: same as 32bit but use

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

for the key path